# How can this C code evaluate to 0 and not 0 at the same time?

Tags: c, obfuscation, sequence-points

I have been trying some **contests** on code obfuscation (I **know** it is **not** a good programming practice, but it was a challenge me and a friend are competing, so there's no need to point out the obvious), and, in one of those, I found the following weird behaviour (code has been reduced to one that still reproduces the behaviour) for the expression `t-scanf("%d",t--?&N:&t)`:

```
int main(int t, int N){
    printf("%d\n",t-scanf("%d",t--?&N:&t));
}

int main(int t, int N){
    printf("%d\n",t-scanf("%d",t--?&N:&t)==0);
}

int main(int t, int N){
    printf("%d\n",t-scanf("%d",t--?&N:&t)!=0);
}
```

If I execute the first piece, **0** will be printed, that is, the expression evaluates to 0.

On the second one, **0** will be printed, that is, the expression does not evaluate a 0.

On the third, **1** will be printed, meaning that the expression does not evaluate to 0.

So the **question** is: What's wrong with these pieces of code?

Comment: You essentially have `t - foo(t--)`, whose behaviour is unspecified/undefined (I don't know which, but it doesn't really matter...)

Comment: By the way, t will be treated as argc, and thus is initialized to 1 if program is called without argument, as I have been doing.

Comment: This questions are the wrost... what is obfuscation good for?

Comment: @iharob It is just a challenge in a programming contest. I know obfuscation is horrible, so don't start judging the question, please.

Comment: @DanielCarvalho it's not about the question, it's about you. If you have the ability to write programs, please don't waste your time in such competitions. Learn useful stuff instead. Of course, this is my opinion and might be wrong, but also it's advice for you.

Comment: @iharob I get your point, but this is part of a training to the ACM. The less amount of time I waste typing the code during those highly constrained hours, the best. I know it doesn't seem much, but the point is learning how to deal with the evaluation program. Knowing the reasons for wrong output is essential; for example, once I got a correct code, but forgot to put "return 0;", what made me get a segmentation fault, costing me 20 minutes.

Comment: @DanielCarvalho interesting, wouldn't a good coding style prevent a lot of those silly errors?

Comment: @iharob Correct, but doing things like these make your realize how the compiler works. Global variables initializes to 0, you can create a main different from the standard, if desired (obviously, only for the competitions), and a lot of interesting stuff. I understand your point of view, and I hate myself for wasting time with this, but I've learnt a lot doing this. Besides, it's only this challenge :)
Let's not make this discussion longer. Thanks for your opinion anyway.

Comment: @BryanChen, it's not something one should do, but it's doable. You can even add more arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These code examples cause undefined behaviour because `t--` is unsequenced with respect to the `t` at the start of the expression.

The sequencing relations here are:

- `t--` is *sequenced-before* the other expressions in the ternary operator
- The arguments to `scanf` are each *sequenced-before* using the return value of `scanf`

However `!=` and `-` have no sequencing relation, so those relations do not constrain `t` to be evaluated before `t--` or vice versa, therefore the behaviour is undefined.

---

As a workaround you could write:

```
int temp = t;
printf("%d\n", temp - scanf("%d",t--?&N:&t));
```

The `t--` is *sequenced-before* the execution of the `scanf` body, so the increment will have safely finished before `scanf` potentially overwrites `t`.

Comment: I'll mark this as accepted pretty soon (I have to wait before accepting). In the meantime, would you happen to know a workaround? (Desired behaviour is that the expression evaluates to any value but 0 to be inserted in a while loop that stops after t+1 executions)

Comment: @DanielCarvalho not sure about your logic but I've put in a workaround that doesn't have UB. Not clear if the initial `t` was intended to be the value before the scanf or the value after it. If the value after, then make `temp` hold the result of `scanf` and output `t - temp`.

Comment: I can't do that because that would make my code bigger (the winner has the smallest code), but thanks for the effort.

Comment: @DanielCarvalho I don't see why you are doing `t--` anyway, unless the initial `t` is supposed to not be read until after `scanf` returns

Comment: t should be read once, and then only N will be read for t loop executions. That is why I have to do t--.

Comment: Also, the implementation must document support for `main` having two `int`-arguments...

Comment: @DanielCarvalho there's no loop in these examples

Comment: @MattMcNabb, yes, I know. I tried to keep question code to a minimal. Don't worry about that; I'm tired of this challenge; already have made a good progress. Thanks anyway for your help.